# hide/show button in datatables row details

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Well, the problem is that i have a custom datatables with 40 rows (for now) and each row has some details of it and recently i added an "edit option" in each row details content.
The code is based in this: https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/row_details.html
But i modified the FormatDetails to this:

```
function fnFormatDetails ( oTable, nTr )
    {   
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
        var sOut = '<input type=\'button\' id=\'hideshow\' value=\'hide/show\'><table id="tablaeditar" class="tablaeditar">';
        sOut += '<tr><td><input id="nombref" placeholder="Nombre de Fantasia" type="textbox" value="'+aData[1]+'" maxlength="40" onkeypress="return permite(event, \'car\')" /></td>' + 
                '<td><input id="titular" placeholder="Titular" type="textbox" value="'+aData[2]+'" maxlength="40" onkeypress="return permite(event, \'car\');" /></td>' +
                '<td><input id="direccion" placeholder="Direccion" type="textbox" value="'+aData[3]+'" maxlength="50" onkeypress="return permite(event, \'num_car\')"/></td></tr>' +
                '<tr><td><input id="telefono" placeholder="Telefono" type="textbox" value="'+aData[4]+'" maxlength="30" onkeypress="return permite(event, \'num\');" /></td>' +
                '<td><input id="email" placeholder="Email" type="textbox" value="'+aData[5]+'" maxlength="40" /></td>' +
                '<td><input id="paginaweb" type="textbox" placeholder="Pagina Web" value="'+aData[6]+'" maxlength="40" /></td></tr>' +
                '<tr><td><input id="comentarios" type="textbox" placeholder="Comentarios" value="'+aData[7]+'"  maxlength="40"></td>' +
                '<td><input id="metros" type="textbox" placeholder="Superficie" value="'+aData[8]+'" maxlength="5" onkeypress="return permite(event, \'num\');" /></td>' +
                '<td align="center"><div class="aceptar"><input type="button" value="Aceptar"></input></div></td></tr>'
        sOut += '</table>';

        return sOut;
    }
```

As you can see i put the whole rows information in inputs, and as it is a long code to show in each row details, i want to put a button which can show and hide the sOut table with class "edittable". Something simple like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/1/

I tried to do this with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#hideshow').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('table.tablaeditar').toggle();
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work

How can i do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: first check with static details. Use jsfiddle.

Comment: the code for static details is almost the same as i showed in http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/1/ , but it doesn't work for me (just in the API's code, of course)

Comment: 1st run your code, then get html and put into jsfiddle.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't have code related to your question posted here.

Comment: @jai so only im asking with live code.

Comment: Here is the full code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/721/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue of event delegation and you have to delegate the event to the static existing parent element or to `document` which is available all the time like below:

change your script to this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#hideshow', function(){
    $(this).next('table.tablaeditar').toggle();
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/1574/)

---

[**Your updated fiddle no 724**](http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/724/)

---

#### Note:

[`.on()` requires `jquery version 1.7+`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Yes absolutely, you have to put this inside `doc ready` block.

Comment: It doesn't work yet, but let me show you the whole code to make it easier to understand: http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/721/

Comment: Is in the row details, i had a problem with the "show/hide details" img. Here is fixed: jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/723 , you have to click the "+" img to display the rows details

Comment: Isint toggle() deprecated in 1.8+ ? is there another better way?

Comment: @SankalpSingha Not exactly you are talking about `.toggle(fn, fn)`. What i posted it is this: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

Or you can even use below toggle scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){
   $("#BtnToggle").click(function(){
      $('#divTogg').toggle(1000);
    });
  });
</script>


<style type="text/css"> #divTogg{width: 200px;height: 100px;border: solid 1px black;background-color:LightGrey;text-align:center; display:none;}</style>
```

Lets give a try.